# How do I change the uploading image file name

Tags: 8, hooks, media

How do I change the image name while uploading through a file uploading field? In drupal 8 whenever I add an image to a file field, it automatically uploads the image file to my S3 bucket. I need to change the image name before uploading because I need to list my image names with a specific pattern. I searched the internet but couldn't find a hook for that auto image uploading.

Answer (score 0):

If you're uploading a file I'm assuming it's within a form, right? You could add a submit handler function using `form_alter()` (or override the `submitForm()` method) and change the file's name using the `$form_state` object's `setValue()` and `getValue()` methods I'm sure.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't do that because that file upload field is in a content type and as soon as I added the file to the file uploading field it gets uploaded to the S3 bucket. So practically I can't get it from submitForm().

Comment: Does it immediately send the file to S3 as soon as the user uploads?

Comment: Yes that is how the Drupal 8 file uploader works.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. Did you build your D8 site from a pre-built setup on S3 or do you develop on a local machine and then deploy? I ask because I can't understand how it would immediately upload the file to S3 before you get the chance to modify it. Do you have an AWS/S3 module installed that does that for you?

Comment: It doesn't matter whether you use S3 or local file storage it always upload the files automatically to the server when selecting. You can create a content type and add a file field. You will see yourself.

Comment: Ah ok, just to clarify that your site's also on S3? Sorry, I was under the impression you were using S3 bucket purely for media storage and uploading the files to there from another server. If your whole site and file system is on S3, you should definitely be able to use hooks to modify the file name.

Comment: And also just to clarify you're using your browser's default file uploader rather than a JS driven one?

Comment: Only the uploading files are going to the S3. I searched but couldn't find any hook for this? Do you have any idea? I am using the default file uploader.

Comment: Surely there must be a contrib module that's doing this no? By default D8 just uploads the file to your local server's file system.

Comment: @iambatman are you using [Flysystem S3](https://www.drupal.org/project/flysystem_s3) OR [S3 File System](https://www.drupal.org/project/s3fs) contrib module?

Comment: I am using S3 File System @NoSssweat

Comment: It would be best to look at the File System module's code to see at what point it uploads to S3. It may be that it supplies its own hook you could use beforehand. If you don't find anything there, you could look at using hook_file_insert and arranging your module and the S3 module's weight in the system table. Module's with a greater weight are executed after those with a lower weight.